# What is the proper RESTful API method to replace an entire collection?

Tags: rest, restful-url

Imagine, We have an Entity `School` and this entity has a one to many relationship with `Student` entity. In other words, there is a collection of `Student`s attached to a given `School`

If we are to replace the entire `Student` collection via a single API call,

```
API_URL/school/:school_id/students
```

which is the best Rest method to go along with. I think `PUT` is only used on an Entity not on a Collection. Hence, available options would be to use either `PATCH` or `POST`

Answer (score 4):

> I think PUT is only used on an Entity not on a Collection

No - [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) is used on a *resource*, not on an entity or collection.

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

The changes that happen to the entities in your domain are a *side effect* of the manipulation of REST resources.  See Jim Webber's talk [REST: DDD in the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc).

If your message body is a replacement representation for the resource, then either POST or PUT is the appropriate method to use

If your message body is a [patch document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2), then you should use POST or PATCH.

If you are concerned that POST would be overloaded, then create a new resource in your design to manage this part of your integration protocol.

Again, heed Jim Webber:

> URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.  Work (ex: issuing commands to the domain model) is a side effect of managing resources.  In other words, the resources are part of the anti-corruption layer.  You should expect to have *many many more resources* in your integration domain than you do business objects in your business domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue. My teammates hate none resource nouns in the path. So in order to pass the API design review and to distinct an operation on whole collection from one on a single resource, I go one level up to the school.

GET /schools/1234

{
"schoolMetadat": "xxxx",
"students": []
}

And PATCH on the students property. An update to a property is always replacement.

Comment: please don't answer questions with issues but with solutions, you should comment the post instead

Answer (score 0):

For updating the entire resource use PUT, for partial update use PATCH.

```
PATCH API_URL/school/:school_id {students: [...]}
PUT API_URL/school/:school_id/students [...]
PATCH API_URL/school/:school_id/students {add: [...], remove: [...]}
```

And don't confuse web services in the presentation layer with ORMs in the data access layer.